# Test Flash on Android device via USB

Tags: android, flash, testing, usb, flash-cs5

I am currently learning Actionscript 3.0, mainly to start developing mobile games for Android.
Device central is really useful to emulate the Flash content running on devices, but I thought there was a way to test directly on the device itself via USB. Am I mistaken here, because I cannot for the life of me find any information on doing this.
I found several guides on how to get the USB connection up, but the actual testing/debugging itself seems to be done exclusively in Flash Builder.
I am using Flash CS5, and I want to test my AS3 projects directly on my Nexus S via USB.
The only guides I can find detail the publishing of Flash projects to Android, which is a fairly lengthy process. Surely there has to be a quicker way to preview content directly on your phone without having to go through the entire process of creating an APK for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you out...

[Getting Started with Adobe AIR for Android](http://www.adobe.com/newsletters/inspire/august2010/articles/article1/index.html)

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Had some initial trouble finding the Flash extension and getting my drivers set up correctly, but I got it working in under 20mins. Thanks a bunch! :)